# AWS Linux yum repository can't find MongoDB packages for install

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, mongodb

I am trying to install the latest version of MongoDB for my 32-bit AWS Linux instance.

I am following [these instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) from the MongoDB documentation.

I have created the `.repo` file in the proper directory with the exact contents:

```
# cat mongodb.repo 
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/i686/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When I go to install MongoDB via `yum`, `yum` tells me it can't find the package(s):

```
# yum install -y mongodb-org
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                       | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                    | 2.3 kB     00:00     
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I've run `yum update` and also tried to add it via `yum-config-manager`.

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: What does `yum repolist` show?

Comment: It shows: `yum repolist

repo id                                                      repo name                                                  status
!amzn-main/latest                                            amzn-main-Base                                             4,520
!amzn-updates/latest                                         amzn-updates-Base                                              5
mongodb                                                      MongoDB Repository                                         0+223
repolist: 4,525`

Comment: Have anything excluded in /etc/yum.conf ?  Such as: exclude=mongodb-org

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Here's the contents: `# cat yum.conf
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=system-release
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=3
deltarpm=0`

Comment: If I use `yum repolist -v` it reveals this about the mongodb repo: `Repo-excluded: 223`. Does this mean that there are 223 packages excluded? Why would that be if there is no setting excluding them?